# PGF align plain TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, plain-tex

I don't get the excepted result with the following code

```
\input tikz
\tikzpicture
  \node[draw,align=center] {Hello \hfil\break World};
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

There is no break after `Hello`. I don't want to use text width and specify the width manually.

Comment: It is too long to include it here hence I would suggest that you consult the manual pages 179-181

Comment: @Rupert: yeah, those text related things don't work too well with plain unfortunately. You can change the `\hfil\break` into `\\\` and you will get the break, but the first line will have a veeeery persistent parindent!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PGF/TikZ has some troubles (at least at the time of this writing; version 2.10) when used with the plain-format, unfortunately.

Your example works as `\tikz[draw,align=center] {Hello\\ World};`, but there are situations where surprising things will happen with plain-format:

```
\tikz\node[draw,align=center,text width=1cm] {Hello World};
```

The above will introduce an interesting (and annoyingly persistent) `\parindent`. A `\noindent` at the start of the node will do nothing. Same with `\parindent0pt`. Same with a style with `execute at begin node` for both of the previous. The `\parindent0pt` needs to be set before the `\node` command for it to work.

Another surprising thing one can run into with plain-format:

```
\tikz\node[draw,align=right,text width=1cm] {Hello World};
```

where PGF/TikZ will try to execute `\raggedleft`, a command which does not exist in plain.

Now, I think I remember reading somewhere that PGF/TikZ issues with plain are being fixed (or have already been fixed?), so the current CVS version might not exhibit these issues.